# VLC - Why is there green stripe at the top

Tags: vlc

[image]

Is there any reason why this happens? when i'm not in vlc this green line doesn't appear

Comment: In VLC, Tools --> Preferences -> video settings. Change Output to either OpenGL or X11. Check what works for your system.

Comment: In VLC, try to go to "Tools" > "Preferences > "Input / Codecs" and select "Hardware-accelerated decoding": "VA-API video decoder via DRM".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools --> Preferences --> video --> video settings --> Full display(check) and output(X11 video output(XCB)) --> Save.
Your Problem will get solved.